# How hide a "search-engine results" div until results are available?

Tags: html, css

I have set up a Google CSE search box and search results, simply as two separate div.

```
<div id="search-box">
    <div class="search-entry">
        <gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox>
    </div>

    <div class="search-results">
        <gcse:searchresults></gcse:searchresults>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I want the results div to be hidden ( = not visible and not taking up any space on my page), until search results are available. Preferably just via css, and "cross-browser/platform").

I have searched this forum for a solution - without success. However, the "Ask Question" page of this forum (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) appears to do exactly what I want, as follows:

```
   <div class="ask-advice-search-container">
         <input type="text" value="" class="search-title" />
         <input type="button" value="Search" class="search-button" />
         <div id="question-suggestions">
         </div>
   </div>
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out the hiding-unhiding "trick". The associated css does not seem to do any (un)hiding...

I'd appreciate any help & insights!

Thanks in advance,

Fred

Comment: The unhiding trick is javascript

Comment: That `input` needs a `label`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html